# How to read the link_to parameter in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to pass below parameter through link_to and not able to figure out how to read this in controller using params.

```
<%= link_to "Remove", user_path(:task => {:id => task.id}), :method => :delete, :data => {:confirm => "You Sure?"} %>
```

parameter from console ( I just replaced the authenticity token with XXX)

```
Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"XXX", "task"=>{"id"=>"1"}, "id"=>"1"}
```

`"task"=>{"id"=>"1"}` - This is the parameter I am trying to access from `user_controller`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a hash inside hash in `params`, you can try this in your `UsersController` -

`params[:task][:id]`

Comment: `!params[:task][:id].nil?` is throwing me error when no parameters are passed. but I need to execute a different action when it is nil. how can I check that in controller

Comment: yes, this error throws when you do not have `params[:task]`. So you can just check whether it is present or not. I would write like this `if params[:task] && params[:task][:id].present?` .

Answer (score 0):

Parameters are passed in a Hash that is in a (key, value) pair,you have to pass keys to read values.
You just need to do

> params[:task][:id]

and you will get "1"